# Find and list all URL-s as clickable links to the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I'm trying to write a javascript what is searching for all of the links on the page, then it is adding them to the bottom, under the original content.

"Document.links" seems to do the finding part, it is also listing them, but they are not clickable. So I tried to add some html codes (startHref and endHref lines), which broke the whole thing of course.

My (non-working) script:

```
var links = document.links;
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  var preLink = document.createTextNode("LINK: ");
  var linkHref = document.createTextNode(links[i].href);
  var lineBreak = document.createElement("br");
  var startHref = document.createElement("a href="");
  var endHref = document.createElement(""");

  document.body.appendChild(preLink);
  document.body.appendChild(startHref);
  document.body.appendChild(linkHref);
  document.body.appendChild(endHref);
  document.body.appendChild(lineBreak);
}
```

If this will work I'd also like to have them listed with a number in front of each line (starting with 1 - could be set in the preLink part) - if not too hard to implement.

Also, is there a way to list not all of the links, but only those matching with something? Like only links with a specific domain. Thank you!

Comment: I think you will find a error in your browser console cause by `var startHref = document.createElement("a href="");` and `var endHref = document.createElement(""");` Also why are you using `a href` in `createElement()` ?

Comment: I know, I was just trying to force the text to be clickable. Had no better idea. :(

Comment: Remove everything from the for loop and just put the following line: `document.body.appendChild[links[i])`. If you wish you can put also a break line between: outside the loop create a variable `var br = document.createElement("br");` and append it in the loop: `document.body.appendChild(br)`.

Comment: var links = document.links; 
    var br = document.createElement("br");  
    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {  
    document.body.appendChild[links[i];  
    document.body.appendChild(br);  
    }

Comment: @JaSon Yes, that is what I was thinking. Does it work for you? Because I had a problem with the break line. I'll post a complete answer with a slight changes.

Comment: Not working (I was trying to format my comment), I'm getting: SyntaxError: missing ] in index expression

Comment: That it is because of this part: `document.body.appendChild[links[i])`. It's my fault, it should be: `document.body.appendChild(links[i]);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already found out, you can get all links in a document with:

```
var links = document.links;
```

Now you have an HTMLCollection. You can iterate through it and display all links. For better layout you can put them in a paragraph (`p`). This would be the loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.appendChild(links[i]);
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

Now all links are appended at the end of the page, every link is on its own line and they are clickable. Please try this out.

EDIT: as of your comment, if I understand it right, you have just to put one additional line:

```
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var p = document.createElement("p");

    // the following line is added
    links[i].innerHTML = links[i].href;

    p.appendChild(links[i]);
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

That line will simply replace the inner HTML of the link with its value for the attribute `href`.

EDIT:

The variable `links` just points to `document.links`. The existing links are therefore removed from their original position and appended to the end. If you try to create new links in the for loop, like `document.createElement("a")` you will create an endless loop, because you're iterating through all links in the document. You remember, the variable `links` is not a snapshot of `document.links` when created, but points to it.

You can work around this with creating an array:

```
var links = [];
// populate the array links
for (var j = 0; j < document.links.length; j++) {
    links.push(document.links[j].cloneNode());
}
```

Now this is a snapshot of all links on the page. Every links is cloned and pushed to the array. Now run the for loop and the original links aren't removed.

If the original link was something like:

```
<a href="http://example.com" id="example" class="example-class" title="click me">This is an example.</a>
```

it will become:

```
<a href="http://example.com" id="example" class="example-class" title="click me">http://example.com</a>
```

But if you want just:

```
<a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a>
```

then you have to adapt the code:

```
  
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = links[i].href;
    a.text = links[i].href; // you can use text instead of innerHTML
    p.appendChild(a);
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

If you want to style the output you can add classes like this:

```
p.classList.add("my-css-class");
```

I hope this helps you to achieve your goal.

Comment: On the right way. :p But it is not showing the URL-s. Now I see like "Menu" and clickable pictures listed there. What I'd need is the whole, pure url-s what they are referring to.

Comment: So should it be like this: if the link is `<a href="http://example.com">Example</a>` you want to make it: `<a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a>`. This means you'd like to replace the text node of the link with the value of its attribute `href`.

Comment: Yes, sorry that I was not clear. I meant it to work the same as the "document.links" by default, just making them clickable. I thought there is just an easy additional step. Turned out not. The one you posted now also not as good. I think "var links" can make problems too (links already exists). Rewritten your code changing that, posting it to a new answer so you can check. That works but it is removing(!) now some of the links and items from the original site.

Comment: Works exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much for the great and detailed guide!